# Use Fontawesome in Openlayers with different icon styles

Tags: font-awesome, openlayers

I want to use different Fontawesome icon styles on my map. So far that's not a problem. But in my case the Icon: 'map-marker-alt' has only one unicode for 4 different styles (https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker-alt?style=regular). So the only style i could access is the regular style. Is it possible to reference to another style like the solid style ?

```
      const markerStyle = new Style({
        text: new Text({
          text: '\uf3c5',
          scale: 1.5,
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          font: 'normal 16px "Font Awesome 5 Pro"',
          fill: new Fill({ color: '#2196F3' }),
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use, the font face weight is what is used to specify the style of icon to use. For the Regular style, the weight to use is 400 so your code needs to change to this:

```
const markerStyle = new Style({
        text: new Text({
          text: '\uf3c5',
          scale: 1.5,
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          font: '400 16px "Font Awesome 5 Pro"',
          fill: new Fill({ color: '#2196F3' }),
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
        })
      });
```